# Footer positioned at bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to position the footer div after all the content on the screen.

If the content doesn't fill the entire height of the window, I'd like to position the footer at the bottom of the window. However, if the content fills the height of the window, I dont want the footer visible.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: "I'd like to position the footer div after all the content on the screen." and "However, if the content fills the height of the window, I dont want the footer visible." somewhat negate each other. leaving just "If the content doesn't fill the entire height of the window, I'd like to position the footer at the bottom of the window."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Great site and great code. (Tape not necessary)